# jQuery .css("margin-left")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

I made a kind of game in javascript and in this game there are some divs which are horizontally moving with different transition times. In this game there is a function which is called each `1/100` seconds. Then it first checks it position with:

```
$("class1").css("margin-left")
```

And now the weird thing: when I set the class in html like:

```
<div class = "class1"></div>
```

The `.css("margin-left")` works perfectly, but when I don't set a class in html and I add the class in js like:

```
$("div:nth-child(6)").addClass("class1");
```

Then the `$(theclass).css("margin-left")` give wrong outputs.
I tried with the .position and .offset but those both didn't work for me.

My code:

```
function newBlock(block, marginTop, bgc, height, hoogte1, hoogte2, v, tijd){
                        block.css("background-color", bgc).css("height", height).css("margin-top", marginTop);
                        var movement1 = "movement1";
                        var movement2 = "movement2";
//                        if (positionPixelsBlockF > 0){
//                            positionPixelsBlockF = positionBlockF.slice(0, 3);
//                        }
                        setInterval(positie, 10);
                        function positie(){
                        tijd = tijd + 1;
                        if (v != 0){
                            block.addClass("i" + v);
                            $(".i" + v).css({"width": "50px", "display": "inline-block", "position": "absolute", "z-index": "20"});
                            var positionBlockF = $(".i" + v).css("margin-left");
                            var positionPixelsBlockF = positionBlockF.slice(0, 4);
                            $("#uitleg4").html(positionPixelsBlockF);
else if (v === 0){
                            var positionBlockF = $(".b1").css("margin-left");
                            var positionPixelsBlockF = positionBlockF.slice(0, 4);
```

Don't mind the incomplete use of the {}, but in my code that's fixed.

PS: using brackets

Comment: What can you see in the debugger on the block element right after block.addClass("i" + v); ? Did you manage to add the class?

Comment: addClass is jQuery function but you are not using jQuery in this: block.addClass("i" + v); You could instead use block.setAttribute("class", "i" + v);

Comment: Yes but I before I want to add the Class "i" + v, I added another class which let the div move the the right site, and I don't want to delete this class, which happens with the .setAttribute, and I also did try it with the .setAttribute but that still doesn't fix my problem. Still thanks for helping (:

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a `dot` before class1 selection, in jquery there are two types of elements selection either by class like `$(".ElemnetClass")` OR by ID like `$("#ElementID")`

More info about [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Yes yes I know that is not the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This Is An Example Of Your Requirement

```
 $(".class").css('margin-left','10px');// Some Px (or) percentage Your Based On Requirement
```

You Can Use This Type Also Firstly You Create One Class Of Your Requirements
 And Use Below Code

```
$("#ElementId").addClass('created classname Here');
```

Comment: Yes I know how to SET the margin-left, but now my question is how to GET margin-left, normally this works with .position.left or offset.left but those don't work for me, so I tried .css("margin-left"), but that one only works if I set the class in html and not if I only add the class in javascript with .addClass